# How to restore a ray-tune checkpoint when it is integrated with Pytorch Lightning?

Tags: python, pytorch, ray, pytorch-lightning, ray-tune

I have a ray tune analysis object and I am able to get the best checkpoint from it:

```
analysis = tune_robert_asha(num_samples=2)
best_ckpt = analysis.best_checkpoint
```

But I am unable to restore my pytorch lightning model with it.

I try:

```
MyLightningModel.load_from_checkpoint(
    os.path.join(analysis.best_checkpoint, "checkpoint")
)
```

But MyLightningModel exposes a config in its constructor so that ray tune can set certain hyperparameters for each trial:

```
class MyLightningModel (pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, config=None):
        self.lr = config["lr"]
        self.batch_size = config["batch_size"]
        self.layer_size = config["layer_size"]

        super(MyLightningModel , self).__init__()
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(768, self.layer_size, num_layers=1, bidirectional=False)
        self.out = nn.Linear(self.layer_size, 1)
```

Thus when I try to run load_from_checkpoint, I get an error in the constructor of MyLightningModel since the config is undefined:

> ---
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> 1 MyLightningModel.load_from_checkpoint(
> ----> 2     os.path.join(analysis.best_checkpoint, "checkpoint")
> 3 )
>
> 2 frames
>  in **init**(self, config)
> 3     def **init**(self, config=None):
> 4
> ----> 5         self.lr = config["lr"]
> 6         self.batch_size = config["batch_size"]
> 7         self.layer_size = config["layer_size"]
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

How is this supposed to be handled?

Comment: I also asked this question on the ray tune forum site but since it can be hard to get responses there, I wanted to ask here as well

Comment: This is being discussed here https://discuss.ray.io/t/how-to-properly-restore-checkpoint-when-using-pytorch-lightning/3895

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default `config` value which in your case is `None`

```py
# constructor takes in an argument
MyLightningModel(config)

# uses the default argument for config which is None
model = LitModel.load_from_checkpoint(PATH)

# override the default parameter
model = LitModel.load_from_checkpoint(PATH, config='path/to/config')
```

Source: https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/checkpointing_basic.html#initialize-with-other-parameters